# Is there a single word for "something people like to hear"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'd like to know if there is a single word for "something people like to hear"

Comment: Please add more context - is this in the sense that they like to hear it because it is a positive comment on them (like a compliment), because it is uplifting (like good news) or because it is pleasing to the ears (like music)?

Comment: To quote Chandler Bing: "You mean music?"

Comment: Your question is off-topic. Please make sure you take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Comment: Can you provide a sentence where the word would be used?

Comment: @Rathony His question does not seem off topic at all - he is, after all, making a word request. However, it would be better served with an example usage/context.

Comment: Applicable to all contexts, and built on the opposite of "ear-piercing noise" you could use "ear-pleasing noise/music/sound/voice"

Comment: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/music+to+ears

Comment: Do you refer to *something melodious* (sound) or to *a compliment* (an expression of praise or admiration) ?

Answer (score 1):

I think **euphony** is what you're after. — [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/euphony)

> agreeableness of sound; pleasing effect to the ear, especially a pleasant sounding or harmonious combination or succession of words

Answer (score 1):

It would help to have more context, but there is a slang term "ear candy" (http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ear+candy) that is close to what you are saying.

Again, this is informal (and yes, it is technically two words), but the term "euphony," while perfectly accurate, is also very formal and rare, so you might consider slang more appropriate in some contexts.